# methods of parsing passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, parsing, subject-complement

> *The show was watched by five million people*.

Am I right there are two approaches to parsing this sentence?:

first approach:
"*Was watched*" is a verb.
The verb "*was watched*" is intransitive.

second approach:
"*Was*" is a verb.
"*Watched by five million people*" is a subject complement.

Do these approaches exist?
Are there any ones else?
Thanks.

Comment: At the moment this question is off-topic as it is just proofreading. You've written some sentences and are asking if they are right. Is there a reason why you think you might be wrong?

Comment: @Astralbee OP is asking about approaches to parsing a passive sentence. What wording makes you think it's proofreading?

Comment: With the first approach, I wouldn't call "watch" intransitive. Transitivity is about underlying [*"thematic roles"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation) like "agent" and "theme", which are independent of the structure of the surface representation. In your sentence, "the show" is the "theme". If a verb has a "theme", then it's transitive, so "watch" is transitive.

Comment: @gotube The only questions are "am I right?" and if there is another way to write it. The definition of proofreading on this site is literally that - asking if something is correct or can be improved.

Comment: @Astralbee Disagree. "Proofreading" is looking for errors in spelling, grammar, semantic, etc. in a given text (here I mean "text" like a phrase, sentence, paragraph, etc). The OP is not asking for us to find errors in any provided text, but asking if there are two approaches to parsing a sentence.

Comment: @gotube then you're disagreeing with the rules of the site you moderate. "**Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading**". The OP's questions are literally that - is this correct, and how could I make it better.

Comment: @Astralbee "is this correct" is just a general question asked when a questioner doesn't know if something is correct or not. To try to attach proofreading to every such question is to try to close this forum as such.

Comment: @Astralbee It's clear enough to me that that sentence has the understood, "*...find and correct errors **in some arbitrary text that you supply**...*". It certainly doesn't mean nobody is ever allowed to ask if anything at all is correct, including ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would not approve either analysis.
I would rather say that:

- "*watched*" is an inflected form of "to watch", the main verb in this sentence. Specifically it is then past participle.
- "*was*" is functioning as an auxiliary verb.
- "*was watched*" uses the auxiliary verb + the main verb to form a **past passive** construction.
- the verb is being used intransitively, so there is no direct object.  The normal object "*the show*" has been moved to the subject position, placing the sentence in the passive voice.
- "*five million people*" serves as an indirect object, introduced by the word "*by*". It indicates the agent, the performer of the action  (watching).

Answer (score 0):

Both aspects of your first approach are incorrect:

- Some people might use the term "verb" to refer to multi-word phrases, but it usually refers to a single word. (In your sentence, "was watched" would more commonly be considered a "verb catena" or similar construction.)
- An intransitive verb can never be put into a passive form.

Your second approach is OK. Some people might not call "watched by five million people" a subject complement, but "subject complement" can certainly be defined in a way that would include it.